# Validation not working (extjs)

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, playframework

I cannot get my code to work. The second if statement is not being read at all for some reason.

```
    function validateStation(v){
    // search store for value... if you find it then true, else false
    if (storeStation.findExact('disp',v) > -1) return true;
    else return 'This value is not valid.';

    if (cbStationFSAC.isValid())  return true;
    else return 'This value is not valid.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function rightfully exits the code after reading the first if/else statement.
Instead try rewriting the code as such

```
function validateStation(v){
    // search store for value... if you find it then true, else false
    if (((storeStation.findExact('disp',v) > -1) || (cbStationFSAC.isValid()))
        return true;
    else 
        return 'This value is not valid.';

 }
```

Comment: extjs does not like the || characters

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this so it executes all the condition before returning the value

```
function validateStation(v){

    var output = true;    

    if (storeStation.findExact('disp',v) > -1)
        output = true;
    else 
        output = 'This value is not valid.';

    if (cbStationFSAC.isValid())  
        output = true;
    else 
        output ='This value is not valid.';

    return output;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else "

Comment: oh its because of the "{" that I have not closed 
let me edit my snippet.